# Error biblioteca mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou tendo problemas com a biblioteca mPDF, procurei na internet alguns tutoriais porém não resolvi meu problema.

quando tento acessar a pagina da um erro :

> Error - mPDF requires mb_string functions. Ensure that PHP is compiled with php_mbstring.dll enabled.

Minha pagina php está programada da seguinte maneira:

```
include("../mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Onde i `$html` é meu html escrito.

Como posso solucionar este problema ?
Existem outra biblioteca para gerar PDF de forma fácil e rápida ?

Estou usando o centos para desenvolver.

Comment: Precisa habilitar o `php_mbstring` no php.ini se não tiver feito ainda.

Comment: qual a linha que habilito ?

Comment: Remova o ponto e vírgula dessa linha => `extension=php_mbstring.dll` e reinicie o apache, faça o teste novamente agora deve funcionar.

Comment: @rray no meu não tem esta linha

Comment: É windows ou linux? veja se existe essa dll na pasta `ext` e adicione a linha comentário anterior.

Comment: meu servidor roda no linux

Comment: Acho que precisa instalar ela, via linha de comanado, coloca na pergunta qual linux vc tá usando, se é ubuntu, debian, centos etc.

Comment: meu linux é cent'os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para instalar a extensão `mb_string` no centos rode a seguinte linha de comanado:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

reinicie o apache e veja se ela foi instalada corretamente, pode procurar no `phpinfo()` por `mbstring`.

**Baseado em:**

[How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278561/1342547)